# Simple way to vertically align a nested div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically align some rows of text within a parent div. Below is a simple example that should explain exactly what I want. It seems so simple, but after hours of searching I still can't find a way to do it! Thanks for any help you can provide.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M9f2a/)

```
<html>
<header>

<style type="text/css">
.outer
{
}
.inner1
{
    float:left;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    background-image:url('http://www.google.com/favicon.ico');
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.inner2
{
    float:left;
    height:80px;
    padding-left:10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.innerText
{
}
</style>

</header>
<body>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner1"></div>
    <div class="inner2">
        <div class="innerText">This text</div>
        <div class="innerText">Should be centered</div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display:table-cell;` instead of `float:left;` in your `inner2` class.

```
.inner2 { 
   height:80px;
   padding-left:10px;
   vertical-align:middle;
   display:table-cell;
}
```

---

[**Working jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ShNMC/)

Comment: Thanks that did the trick! I'll mark you as correct as soon as it lets me.