# How to keep text on a single line without wrapping the div?

Tags: html, css

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TFL5y/) of what I'm trying to do. I want both sentences to be on one line each, and ellipsize if they run off the page. This works for the first sentence, but the second sentence makes the whole `inner2` div get pushed down if it gets cut off. My code is also below.

Clarification: This only happens when the window is made very small. The whole `inner2` div jumps down below the image, when instead it should ellipsize both rows of text. I want both lines of text to be to the right of the image, and vertically centered.

**Update:** As posted by Andrew Clody, [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Scq7/) is much closer to my desired result. The div no longer jumps, but the second row of text does not ellipsize. My desire is for both rows of text to ellipsize.

```
<html>
<header>

<style type="text/css">
.outer
{
}
.inner1
{
    float:left;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    background-image:url('http://www.google.com/favicon.ico');
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.inner2
{
    display:table-cell;
    height:80px;
    padding-left:10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.text1
{
    padding-right:5px;
    float:left;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.text2
{
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
</style>

</header>
<body>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner1"></div>
    <div class="inner2">
        <div class="text1">This long sentence</div>
        <div class="text2">should definitely all be on one line</div>
        <div class="text2">This should all be on the next line and not wrap</div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do they need to be in divs?... becasue normally. you dont put `one` sentence spread out over 3 divs lol

Comment: In my application, there is an "event title" followed by a "genre" and they have different styles but are on the same line. The remaining lines all have the same style as the "genre."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use spanns for that. check it out: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zUESK/)

```
<span class="event">Event here</span> <span class="genre">Genre here</span>
    <span class="something">Maybe something more</span>

.event{
    color:blue;
    font-size:20px;
}

.genre{
    color:green;
    font-size:15px;
}
.something{
    font-size:12;
    color:red;
}
```

Edit// here is the good fiddle :) [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HMAM5/4)

Comment: Ah, this is what I was looking for. I will play around with this and let you know how it works.

Comment: @Kevin ? why not? you give the first part, a bold, i see bold, you gave 5px padding, i see 5px padding

Comment: When you make the window smaller, the whole div jumps below the image

Comment: what browser are you using? see nothing in my FF and how do you want to react it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30073/discussion-between-diederikeen-and-kevin)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! The final solution is here http://jsfiddle.net/HMAM5/4/

Answer (score 1):

I think that `display:table-cell` on the .inner2 class is what was causing the problem.

I realize that you were using this to vertically center the text - but this can also be achieved with some top padding.

Also I added overflow:auto to trigger a block formatting context on the inner2 class so that it takes up the remaining horizontal space. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-div-to-take-remaining-width) for more info.

Here's un updated <kbd>**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/qxLGA/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: That fiddle is exactly what I need, I'm confused how it works though; in a previous question I determined I NEEDED the table-cell display to fix a separate issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575533/simple-way-to-vertically-align-a-nested-div/16575557)

Comment: This does appear to be what I'm looking for, however I would prefer to do it without the top padding. I want this to be as extensible as possible, because in the future I will likely make the image resize depending on the screen. This is for mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

To get the behavior I think you're searching for, the parent needs to be a table-row.

```
.outer
{
    display:table-row;
}
```

Edit: New Fork

http://jsfiddle.net/4Scq7/

Comment: So far this looks like the winner. How can I get the second row to ellipsize though?

Answer (score 0):

Just simply take the div outside of the inner2 div and it works, as it then won't float (wrap)

jsfiddle.net/TFL5y/3/

Comment: I want both lines of text to be to the right of the image, and vertically centered. Sorry this wasn't clear, I've updated the question.

Comment: what about something like this jsfiddle.net/TFL5y/4/

Comment: I need the text to ellipsize, not wrap.

Comment: Thanks for showing me something new, i didn't know you could do this until i just solved it lol